# How Siri is turned ON in Car?

Tags: ios

I wants to know how Car steering wheel control is able to turn ON the Siri via bluetooth.
Also, have a look at this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU8AfEW_QEA
How this is working?
Thanks

Comment: Technically its not possible yet! You need to make physical contact to phone.

Comment: Thats not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye you need to ask the question you actually want answered. This is not the question you want answered and is a duplicate.

Comment: Give us details about what you are trying to do. Asking things like "How does this device work" is useless because 1. no one other than  the engineers of that device knows how it works. 2. we still have no idea about what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a thing called CarPlay which is built into the car by the car manufacturer.

If there is any way of doing this yourself then have a search for "CarPlay" but I don't think it's available as an API.

Comment: Yes, I know CarPlay and their API is not public.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye if you knew this then I struggle to understand why you asked the question.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know the CarPlay mechanism. How iPhone is able to turn Siri ON after receiving signal from steering wheel control.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye the only people that will know this are engineers at Apple. There a many possible ways of doing this. How Apple implemented it is a guess for anyone.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU8AfEW_QEA   How this is working?

Comment: This device is able to activate Siri on iPhone.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye I imagine it registers itself with the iPhone as a bluetooth headset. Any bluetooth headset can activate siri if it has a button on it dedicated to that function. However, this is nothing to do with CarPlay. This is activating Siri over Bluetooth.

Comment: @Hawk-Eye I'd suggest changing your question so that you are asking EXACTLY what you want to know. I'm guessing that you are trying to create a device that activates siri? Or something like this... but you haven't ever said this so it's hards to know what you are asking.